# Modify checkbox event on custom line item type to hide show div

Tags: javascript, forms, commerce

I have a block of custom length fields and a rule to figure them and put the correct total in the cart however I want to hide the div that contains them unless the exact lengths checkbox is checked

[image: Exact Lengths Needed Image]

however currently this always shows on my test site and from how the site is set up now with a paragraph of instructions and a textbox i've found that people are lazy and don't read directions.  so I don't want to give anyone the opportunity to fill in fields without the checkbox checked

I have tried using JS_Injector to add some js to hide and show but it only seems to be able to add js to the header or footer which doesn't help me add it to the form on the checkbox change event does anyone have any other suggestions short of telling me to write a module with a hook_form_alter()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module should do the job.

It allows you to create rules to hide or show fields based on another fields value - so perfect for you.

Comment: this will work even if I can't hide and show the div with it and have to do the fields individually

Comment: Yes, you will have to do the fields individually but will still work...

Comment: yea I already tried it and I have to change the header on my div but it still accomplishes what I want it to Thank You